# Add STD to legend in python seaborn

Tags: python, histogram, data-visualization, seaborn, legend

I have the chart below and I would like to add STD per class in the legend.

[image]

It was created with the code:

```
subset1=data1[feats_to_explore+['wine_class']]
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(7,14), sharey=True)

l=[ax1,ax2,ax3]
colors=['lime','deeppink','dodgerblue']

## La única modificación se da en la incorporación de la línea vertical con las medias.
for graph in l:
    for i in (subset1['wine_class']).unique():
        df =subset1[subset1.wine_class == i]
        sns.distplot(df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]],  kde=False, label=i, ax=graph, color=colors[int(i)])
        graph.axvline(df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]].mean(),color=colors[int(i)])  
        graph.legend(title='Wine Class')
```

I would like to add in the right side of the tag (0.0, 1.0 or 2.0) the std for each group. Is there somebody that can support me on this issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Finally I reached the solution. I present you in the lines below in case someone needs it:

```
tipo=['Class 0','Class 1','Class 2']
for graph in l:
    w=[str(x) for x in np.around((subset1.groupby('wine_class').std()[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]]).to_numpy(),decimals=2)]
    for i in (subset1['wine_class']).unique():
        df =subset1[subset1.wine_class == i]
        sns.distplot(df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]],  kde=False, label=i, ax=graph, color=colors[int(i)])
        graph.axvline(df[feats_to_explore[l.index(graph)]].mean(),color=colors[int(i)])  
        graph.legend([str(tipo[i]) +": "+ str(w[i]) for i in range(len(tipo))],title='wine_class')
```

[image]